# Android suspend mode

Tags: android, linux

What mechanism let the (OS) daemons know that the phone enters the sleep/suspend mode in Android?

Does the init process (which is the parent of all daemons) send a kill signal when the phone switch to suspend mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is controlled through wake locks.  There isn't something deciding when to put the CPU to sleep; apps hold a wake lock to prevent it from going to sleep.  If there are no wake locks being held, the CPU goes to sleep and will not come back out of sleep until an external event (button press, network activity, alarm) wakes it up.

Comment: In fact my question was a little bit different. When the phone decides to go to suspend mode (e.g. request_suspend_state), somehow the daemons get to now this and start sending data to the drivers over ioctl. However daemons are part of user space and according to the standard linux implementation user space programs are not supposed to  take any action during suspend/wake up cycle.

Comment: So again the question is still open: what tells the daemons that the phone is going to suspend? Unfortunately daemons are all close source. That is why I cannot check program flow.